# C++: int array[a][b][c] = {0}; not setting all values to 0. Is that instruction wrong or is there something wrong with my output function?

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array, initialization

i initialize the matrix and call the output like this in int main()

```
int array[a][b][c] = {0};
OMat3(a,b,c,(int*)array);
```

this is the output function

```
void OMat3(int rig,int col,int pro,int *mat){
    for (int a=0;a<rig;a++){
        printf("\n%da Materia:\n",a+1);
        for (int b=0;b<col;b++){
            printf("\n\t%d Giorno: ",b+1);
            for (int c=0;c<pro;c++){
                printf("%d  ",mat[a*col*pro+b*pro+c]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that in the output i don't get only 0s (there are mostly 0, but sometimes there are crazy high values).

Am I initializing it to 0 wrong or is there something wrong with my output function?

example program

```
void OMat3(int rig,int col,int pro,int *mat){
    for (int a=0;a<rig;a++){
        printf("\nRow %d:\n",a+1);
        for (int b=0;b<col;b++){
            printf("\n\tColumn %d: ",b+1);
            for (int c=0;c<pro;c++){
                printf("%d  ",mat[a*col*pro+b*pro+c]);
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int a,b,c;
    printf("Insert the array's dimensions: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
    int array[a][b][c] = {0};
    OMat3(a,b,c,(int*)array);
}
```

*I'm using TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release if that's important*

Comment: declare the array as a global variable and you'll have all zeroes by default

Comment: If the array is dynamic then you should use a vector where you can specify the default value for all of the elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @NathanOliver so di i need to create another function to set all values to 0?

Comment: `int array[a][b][c] = {0};`  This is not legal C++ if `a`, `b` or `c` are variables.

Comment: That's not an example program. You just rearranged the code that you already presented. You didn't try to compile or run that program.

Comment: @AndyG Thank you! It works

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Is it good now?Anyway problem solved.

Comment: @AndyG *Hmm, it does seem to be acting a little weird with ={0}* -- It's acting weird because it isn't supposed to even work for C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Good catch.... but I'm confused as to why it compiles. Can you shed some light on it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I'm not sure how you were able to grab that comment, I deleted it after you pointed that out!

Comment: @AndyG It is an extension offered by `gcc`.  With extensions, you need to read the documentation on what it does and how it behaves.  Otherwise you're taking a gamble if you just assume it works the same way as a static array.  That gamble may work for most scenarios you use an array for, but obviously it failed for the initialization syntax for `{0}`.

Comment: @AndyG solved my problem, using {} instead of {0} works. I'm new here, how do i mark this post as solved?

Comment: @Dema: You do that by marking one of the answers as the solution (choosing a checkmark). I deleted my comment because it wasn't entirely accurate.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: You should summarize your comments into an answer, which should be marked as the soln.

Comment: @Dema -- If this is for a school assignment, be very careful of the answer that you are getting.  Again, declaring arrays using variables as the number of items is *not* valid C++ syntax, and if you're being graded on using proper syntax, then you may be getting the wrong advice.  As a matter of fact `-Wall -pedantic` compiler flags for `g++` will give you the error I'm speaking of.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Actually this is for a program i'm making for personal use

Comment: @Dema -- I gave an answer showing how to alleviate this issue.  It works the same as your example, and it is valid C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this is not legal C++ syntax:

```
int a,b,c;
//...
int array[a][b][c] = {0};
```

The issue is that C++ does not allow declaring arrays with a variable being used as the number of items.  So `a`, `b`, or `c` cannot be used in the array declaration.  An array's size must be declared using a *compile-time* expression, not a value determined at runtime.

What you are using is an extension offered by GCC, namely `Variable Length Arrays`.  If you compiled your code using `-Wall -pedantic` flags for `g++`, you will get the error that I am speaking of.

The way you can alleviate this is to use `std::vector<int>`.

```
#include <vector>
//..
int a, b, c;
//..assume a, b, and c have values
std::vector<int> array(a*b*c);
//... call the function
OMat3(a, b, c, array.data());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `array[a][b][c]={}` works as intended and initializes all of the values to 0

Thanks to @AndyG for finding out that.